# Pixel-wise classification on a large image using Unet and .npy dataset

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, dataset, classification, conv-neural-network

I have an image ~(5000*5000*8).I converted this big image to small images(eg:400 images with 256*256*8 dim (x,y,channel)) and imported those to numpy array.now I have an array (400,256,256,8) for one of my class and another array (285,256,256,8) for my second class and I save these arrays to npy files. I want to classify this images pixel by pixel, I have a label matrix with 2 class. now I want to classify this image by a UNET customised method and I use deep cognition and peltarion websites to config my network and data, so I need a method to help me for classify my image pixel-wise. please help me.

Comment: What is your specific problem? What have you tried before? What is not working? Also, it's better to say "segmentation" than "pixel-wise classification".

Comment: first I dont know how to adjust my dataset because my images are in .tff format and not supported in very framework and these image are 8 channel and i cant convert them to another format.I convert them to .npy to use them in peltarion platform but dataset doesn't import correct.first problem this is. second problem is about sementation or pixel wise classification that I dont know how must do it